# Colocar as opções de um input select em uma variavel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa noite.

É possivel em um select multiple eu salvar as opções escolhidas numa variavel e manter as opções escolhidas?

Exemplo:

```html
<form class="form-inline">
<select id="opcoes" multiple name=opcoes[] >
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
        <option value="3">Option3</option>
    </select>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Se sim, como posso recuperar isso e reaproveitar no mesmo select?

Comment: Desculpe-me, mas `$("#opcoes").val()` já não retorna a lista de valores selecionados? O que quer dizer sobre "salvar em uma variável e manter as opções escolhidas"?

Comment: É possível! Tente pegar o valor no evento change. Como o campo é múltiplo, será retornado um array.

Answer (score 2):

Então, `<select multiple />` tem um atributo chamado `selectedOptions` que retorna as `<option />` escolhidas. Então basta passar por elas no evento `onChange` mesmo. Com Javascript puro fica assim:

```js
var selecionadas = [];
var opcoes = document.querySelector('#opcoes');
opcoes.addEventListener('change',    function(ev){
   var selectedOptions = ev.target.selectedOptions;
   selecionadas = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++){
      selecionadas.push(selectedOptions[i].value);
   }
   console.log(selecionadas);
});
```

```html
<form class="form-inline">
<select id="opcoes" multiple name=opcoes[] >
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
        <option value="3">Option3</option>
    </select>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Por quê não utiliza apenas `$("#opcoes").val()` para recuperar os valores selecionados?

Comment: Boa pergunta! Não sei, vou alterar.

Comment: Se bem que as outras já usam, então deixa essa como uma resposta diferente mesmo. Nem sempre você vai ter o jQuery, então é bom saber como se faz em JS puro.

Comment: Isso, com certeza. Então talvez, para aumentar "a beleza" da resposta, poderia implementá-la toda com JS puro, visto que a única ferramenta do jQuery que utiliza é apenas a função `on` e poderia ser subsituída facilmente pela `addEventListener`.

Comment: Valeu pela dica @AndersonCarlosWoss !

Comment: @Daniel uma forma contraída seria.: `var selecionados = [].slice.call(e.target.selectedOptions).map(o => o.value))`

Comment: @TobiasMesquita não sei se vale tanto contrair código desse jeito, a menos que você esteja tentando conseguir performance alta, na minha opinião é melhor manter o código bem legível. Eu realmente deveria usar o método ``map`` no entanto, ao invés de um ``for``, que fica melhor pra ler também.

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim, ainda mais usando Jquery, há diversas formas, se não me engano voce pode bindar um evento por exemplo: "onClick" nas opções e aí quando o usuário clicar você executa uma função que adiciona ou remove esse valor no array, no caso o valor da option que você passando a option como argumento poderia pegar assim: `$(option).val();` para passar a option como argumento você pode fazer assim

```
<option value="1" onClick="adicionarNoArray(this)">Option1</option>
```

Desculpe-me pelos "Se não me engano", faz tempo que não mecho com jQuery, mas vou até testar e depois posto um comentário aqui dizendo se funcionou ou não.

**EDIT**

```
<html>
        <head>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
                <select id="select" multiple>
                        <option value="1" onClick="adicionarArray(this)">Option1</option>
                        <option value="2" onClick="adicionarArray(this)">Option1</option>
                        <option value="3" onClick="adicionarArray(this)">Option1</option>
                </select>

        <script>
                var valores = [];
                function adicionarArray(option)
                {
                        var index = valores.indexOf($(option).val());
                        if(index != -1)
                        {
                                valores.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                valores.push($(option).val());
                        }
                                console.log(valores);
                }
        </script>
        <body>
</html>
```

Isso deve resolver o seu problema. Talvez não seja a melhor forma de fazer e outro pode vir com uma resposta melhor, porém assim você consegue colocar os valores conforme forem selecionados num array e trabalhar com os valores.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>Resposta</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="opcoes" multiple name="opcoes">
    <option value="1" class="selecionar">Option1</option>
    <option value="2" class="selecionar">Option2</option>
    <option value="3" class="selecionar">Option3</option>
  </select>

</body>

<script>
  opcoes = []
  $(".selecionar").click(function(e){
    $('#opcoes :selected').each(function(i, selecionado){
      if($.inArray(selecionado,opcoes) == -1){
        opcoes.push(selecionado);
      }else{
        opcoes.splice(i,1);
      }
    });
    console.log(opcoes);
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Por quê não utiliza apenas `$("#opcoes").val()` para recuperar os valores selecionados?